# How can I inject the global dataSource into the .extend( )ed Repository

Tags: typescript, dependency-injection, nestjs, typeorm, nestjs-typeorm

according to the lasttest typeorm doc, Custom repositories can be created using the .extend() method of type 'Repository'.

using nestJS, I have a global dataSource that I can inject into Services. this is very good if you're only goin to need that dataSource inside *.service.ts files, but if you have a repository Object like say usersRepository in user.repository.ts and you try to extend it like so:

```
//user.repository.ts

const usersRepository = dataSource.getRepository(User).extend({
  async createUser(authCredentialsDto: AuthCredentialsDto): Promise<void> {
    const user = this.create(authCredentialsDto);
    await this.save(user);
})

export default usersRepository
```

where should ***dataSource*** be imported from? given that the only typeOrmConfig I have is in the TypeOrmModule:

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    TypeOrmModule.forRootAsync(TypeOrmAsyncConfig),
    UserModule,
    AuthModule,
  ],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

thought about ditching the repository file and creating the Repository inside of the Service file, while injecting the dataSource there. But that means that every time you need the specific methods inside that Repository you'd have to rewrite everything inside the current service.